# .htaccess Redirect loop on apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After moving a website to a new server running apache 2.4, this website no longer works and gives a 500 server error.

The current .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The index.php files handles the urls as follows:

```
<div role="main">

         <?php
            // Defualt page will always be home.html
            $page = 'home';

            // Lets get pages based on user input 
            if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {

              //Assign a variable to a sanitised version of the data passed in the URL
              $tmp_page = basename($_GET['name']);

              //If the file exists, update $page
               if (file_exists("pages/{$tmp_page}.html")) 
                  $page = $tmp_page;

              //If the file does not exist, include our custom notfound page and don't run anymore code   
               elseif(!file_exists($tmp_page)){
                  include("pages/notfound.html");
                  exit;
              }
            }

            // Include our default page declared above if no data is passed (no clicks on menu)
            include("pages/$page.html"); 
            ?>

  </div>
```

I have not been able to fix this by just changing the .htaccess. I'm only hosting the website, so ideally I do not want to make changes to the website without the designer's consent.

Comment: Take a look at your first condition/rule pair... it basically says: if the request is actually an existing physical file, then rewrite to that file. Certainly that is a rewrite loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first rule  rewrites files to files, that is why you are getting a Rewrite loop error.

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```